# MongoDB LVM snapshots backup and restore on diffent filesystems

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ebs, ext4, lvm, xfs

I want to backup a large MongoDB database (aprox. 100GB) using LVM snapshot, but the filesystem differs from the backup to restore point.
The actual database resides on AWS EBS with **ext4** filesystem and I want to restore it in another EBS with **XFS**.

Actually, I can perform this operation?

Comment: LVM here is not a factor. The real question should be "is it safe to copy my data from an ext4 to an xfs filesystem?

Comment: I want to prevent data loss, that was the real reason of the question, sorry by the lack of clarity. Any other concerns about this operation?

Comment: Actually it was clear enough. I was a bit confused when I read lvm :) But the question is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Just make sure to copy all the data using `rsync` with the following options:
`rsync -a -AHX -S /lvsnap_mountpoint/ /destination`